# Make \exp_not:V and \exp_args:NV work for fp variables too?

Tags: expl3, expansion, fp

In `interface3` the description of `\exp_not:V` command is the following:

```
\exp_not:V ⟨variable⟩
Recovers the content of the ⟨variable⟩, then prevents expansion of
this material in x-type or e-type arguments using \exp_not:n.
```

From the following example, I can see that `\exp_not:V` can recover `tl`, `str`, `dim`, `int` variables, but can not recover `fp` variables. Can we make `\exp_not:V` work for `fp` variables too?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {tl}
\use:e { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl }
\par

\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {str}
\use:e { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_str }
\par

\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {1pt}
\use:e { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_dim }
\par

\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {1}
\use:e { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_int }
\par

\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {1.2}
\use:e { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_fp }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

**Update**: I forgot to mention `\exp_args:NV`. It is the same that `\exp_args:NV` can recover `tl`, `str`, `dim`, `int` variables, but can not recover `fp` variables, either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {tl}
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {str}
\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {1pt}
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {1}
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {1.2}

\exp_args:NV \use:n \l_tmpa_tl \par

\exp_args:NV \use:n \l_tmpa_str \par

\exp_args:NV \use:n \l_tmpa_dim \par

\exp_args:NV \use:n \l_tmpa_int \par

\exp_args:NV \use:n \l_tmpa_fp \par

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

There are some workarounds for `fp` variables. But what I want is a single command for recovering the centent of any type of variables listed above.

Comment: It is possible, but it slows down usage of `V`-type expansion everywhere else. Due to that, and to longer-term plans regarding usage of `fp` vars, we haven't implemented that

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Can you provide an answer for this? Is it possible for an user to do this without touching private macros of `expl3` (i.e., define a `\exp_not_improved:V` macro)?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Also, where can I find the longer-term plans regarding usage of `fp` vars? Why are they related to this question?

Comment: No, to make `V` work with `fp` you need to detect an `fp` variable by looking at the leading `\s__fp`. The “plans” I mentioned were just an e-mail Bruno sent regarding this topic (it came up just a few days ago), that he'd like to change `fp` variables to “just work”

Comment: For the moment you can do `e` expansion on `{\fp_eval:n{<expression>}}`

Comment: Note that `V`-type expansion does work from the point of view that you get a representation of the value, it's just that unlike a `tl` or similar, it's not a conveniently human-readable form.

Comment: @JosephWright Please see my updated question.

Comment: `\exp_not:V` would mean little sense for an `fp` variable, because its final expansion consists of unexpandable tokens; it would be like doing it for a `str` variable.

Comment: Sometimes you do have to either touching the private macros of expl3 I guess. It just doesn't expose enough interface to avoid. (alternatively maybe discuss with LaTeX3 team and make a pull request. Function to SKHEBG if something is fp variable shouldn't be too hard)